# Can't find a way to correctly print a string correctly with nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I am writing a simple OS which prints all stdin (keyboard input) to stdout (the screen). I want to print a welcome string before the input. I'm using NASM since it is readable and easy to use.

I've tried two ways to print the string:

(Assume `welcome` is defined as `db "Welcome to TextEditOS! Type whatever you want below.",0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah,0`. Remove the `0` for #2.)

1. Using a loop similar to a `while` loop. Originally I used `bx` instead of `si` since a few tutorials did it that way, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61373248/12596701) suggested using `si` since `bx` is used for the page number and color in TTY mode.

```
mov si, welcome
mov ah, 0eh

printWelcome:
    cmp [si], byte 0
    je mainLoop
    mov al, [si]
    int 0x10
    inc si
    jmp printWelcome
```

2. Using `int 10h` where `ah=13h`. The code I used is something like this, though I believe I have the original code on my home computer (I'm away right now, will update this question once I get back).

```
    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax
    xor bh, bh
    mov bp, welcome

    mov ah, 0x13
    mov bl, 0ah ;this was something else I think
    mov al, 1   ;write mode
    mov cx, 56  ;length
    mov dh, 0   ;x
    mov dl, 0   ;y

    int 0x10
```

Both of these work just fine in QEMU. However, when I burn the full code onto a USB flash drive and boot it, the first way prints around 1-2 screens of invisible characters before stopping in the middle of the screen, and the other seems to print an `@` and nothing else. The rest of my code, which is the keyboard input, works fine both ways.

Here is the full code for my operating system:

```
[org 0x7c00]

jmp short start

db 90h,90h,"TEXTOS",20h,20h

section .text

start:

; First, let's set up the stack
mov bp, 7c00h
mov sp, bp

; Insert either way I used to print the string below

; end print func

mainLoop:
    mov ah, 0    ; get keyboard input
    int 16h
    mov ah, 0eh  ; print char
    int 10h      ; al already has the char to print
    cmp al, 13   ; is char 0dh?
    je newLine
    cmp al, 8    ; is char 08h?
    je backSpace
    jmp mainLoop ; loop

newLine:
    mov al, 10   ; complete \n with 0ah
    int 10h
    jmp mainLoop

backSpace:
    mov al, 32   ; insert space over last char
    int 10h
    mov al, 8    ; then another backspace to go back
    int 10h
    jmp mainLoop

welcome: ; welcome message
    db "Welcome to TextEditOS! Type whatever you want below.", 0dh, 0ah, 0dh, 0ah, 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
; Boot signature
dw 0xaa55
```

Commands used to compile and run:

```
nasm boot.asm -fbin -oboot.img
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=boot.img,format=raw
```

As said above, I will find the code for #2 and edit this question with it. I will also try to upload some GIFs of what I get on real hardware.

Comment: Any chance this is related? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320115/3857942

Comment: @MichaelPetch I added the BPB and the same issue occurs, though I noticed my USB drive appears _first_ in the boot drive list. I confirmed my BPB is not being overwritten by the BIOS as well.

Comment: One possible problem I guess is that you set up SP but don't set SS to 0 (SS could be something other than 0 when the BIOS jumps to bootloader code). I assume you mean to have the stack grow down beneath the bootloader (0x0000:0x7c00) which why I suggest ensuring SS=0x0000

Comment: I see you say you have code that does `xor ax, ax` `mov es, ax` . Is there a reason you aren't setting DS to 0 rather than ES? The values in DS, ES, SS can't be assumed to be 0 when your bootloader is reached. It's unclear why you set ES to 0 unless you have code you aren't showing that relied on it. Your code clearly expects DS to be 0 though. Try setting DS to 0 and see what happens. This could explain why it prints garbage as it is referencing the wrong memory location for the string.

Comment: I set `ss` to 0 but it still does not work.

Comment: Here's the thing. The complete code of your bootloader doesn't do what the rest of the question is about. It gets a key and prints it out where as the rest of what you wrote is about printing strings but it is just code snippets. I see now why you used ES:BP because in some code you used Int 10h/AH-13h (BIOS write string). What you really should do is show the exact code that fails and a screenshot of the output would be nice,

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to post my code just in case there was a bug somewhere else. I will also post screenshots soon. I haven't had time to do it, sorry.

Comment: I still don't understand... How am I supposed to correctly print strings?